# how to design a high performance distribution system with a shared resource?

Tags: performance, architecture, distributed-computing, distributed-system

My project has a problem with CPU performance for signle server. I think make the project to a distribution system would a way to handle this problem. But, my project core part is based on a shared resource(a map with roads info) which is probobly changed by tons of client at the 30ms level. Any client would change part of the shared map.

The problem is that server needs the all map info to calculate. And the map would be a high frequency write and read resouce. If use data syncronized middleware, like a redis cluster, I think it can not support the 30ms level considering of the network time cost.

Is there any middleware or system model able to handle it?

Comment: does the server reading the map have to work on the most up-to-date 30-ms version of the map?

Comment: @root yeap, server has to use the up-to-date map to calculate

Comment: With these requirements it looks like scaling up is the only path. But I have doubts that these requirements are valid.